POST request with Java HTTP Client to Grizzly HTTP server times out
I'm in the process of upgrading our projects to Java21, and here I encountered our grizzly http server is not compatible with Java21 (was using version 3.0.1). Thus I upgraded to 3.0.16 and at least it starts again.
But, I'm not able anymore to send POST requests to my server. On the client side I'm using the internal Java HTTP client. (GET works fine)
On the client side I get:
java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException: request timed out
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:954)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:133)
    at com.test.client.Main.main(Main.java:36)

On the server side I get:

Unhandled exception occurred - null
java.io.EOFException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.read(TCPNIOTransport.java:575)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTemporarySelectorReader.readNow0(TCPNIOTemporarySelectorReader.java:40)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read0(TemporarySelectorReader.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read0(TemporarySelectorReader.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:84)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractReader.read(AbstractReader.java:43)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.read(DefaultFilterChain.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.read(FilterChainContext.java:662)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.blockingRead(InputBuffer.java:1037)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.ServerInputBuffer.blockingRead(ServerInputBuffer.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.fill(InputBuffer.java:1060)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOInputStreamImpl.read(NIOInputStreamImpl.java:60)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream.read(EntityInputStream.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.innate.io.InputStreamWrapper.read(InputStreamWrapper.java:54)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:220)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:716)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._verifyNoTrailingTokens(ObjectReader.java:2247)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:2104)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1249)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:829)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:49)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1072)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:657)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:50)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:356)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)

I tried to reproduce w/ a standalone very simple maven project, and it's still the same. I put it online and it's available here: https://github.com/divadpoc/grizzly-test
Can anybody put me in the right direction?
Update
I downgraded step by step until 3.0.11 (or 3.1.3), where it starts to work as expected.
when I stay on the latest version (3.0.16, or 3.1.9) and I explicitly set the HTTP version to 1.1, on the client, the body can be read by the server, and the response is sent.
I described the behaviour in this issue as well, as I'm curious why this is how it is

Calling the server with cURL works...

I updated my pom to use Java17, but no change. I also tried with undertow, on the client I get the following response:
Response status: 500
Response body: Error processing request: UT000035: Cannot get stream as startBlocking has not been invoked


when downgrading to version 3.0.11 everything works fine, but all versions above do not work for me. but I might just be missing something ...

I don't think you are missing something: debugging both situations (Java client and cURL), it seems that the JSON object reader continues to try parsing the JSON after the "}" without detecting the end of stream correctly… so the "this._verifyNoTrailingTokens" raises the exception… (the int count = this._inputStream.read(this._inputBuffer, 0, space); in _loadMore() to be precise)
